# How to log request and response in soap message format while consuming a soap service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, log4j2

Consuming a soap web service.

```
    Report report = new Report()
    report.setUsername("test");
    report.setPassword("test123");

    System.out.println("Going to make the request .....");
    logger.info("Request :" +report)

    SetReportResponse response =(SetReportResponse) soapConnector.callWebService("http://10.88.12.16/ws/_REQUEST_FEEDBACK/services/Feedback.FeedbackHttpSoap11Endpoint/", report);
    logger.info(response.getReturn());
```

How can I log the request and response in xml format, exactly how it send to the client. Just like below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.mogk">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
```

Has suggested in one post add the below entries in application properties, but it didnt help.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
logging.level.org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
```

Using **Spring Boot 2** and **log4j2**

Log4j2.xml - Enabled org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">D:\Logs/MA</Property>
        >
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>

        <Console name="CONSOLE_APPENDER" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>



        <!-- this file will have all the logging done with log.info others will 
            not come in this file due to usage of the filters -->
        <RollingFile append="true" name="FILE_APPENDER_IFNO"
            fileName="${log-path}/mk-trace.log" filePattern="${log-path}/msa-trace-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>

            <Policies>
                <!-- <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy /> -->
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                <!-- <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="24" modulate="true" /> -->
            </Policies>

            <Filters>

                <!-- First deny warn, error and fatal messages -->
                <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY"
                    onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"
                    onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"
                    onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />

                <!-- Then accept info, warn, error, fatal and deny debug/trace -->
                <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="ACCEPT"
                    onMismatch="DENY" />
            </Filters>

        </RollingFile>
        <!-- this fill will contain all the errors like log.error -->
        <RollingFile append="false" name="FILE_APPENDER_ERROR"
            fileName="${log-path}/mk-error.log" filePattern="${log-path}/msa-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d %p [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="24"
                    modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>


    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE_APPENDER_IFNO" level="INFO" />
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE_APPENDER_ERROR" level="ERROR" />
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE_APPENDER" level="INFO" />
        </Root>

        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing">
            <level value="TRACE" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </logger>
        <!-- Spring Webservice XML -->

        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received">
            <level value="TRACE" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </logger>


        <logger name="org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.sent">
            <level value="TRACE" />
            <appender-ref ref="console" />
            <appender-ref ref="file" />
        </logger>
    </Loggers>
    <!-- TRACE->DEBUG->INFO->WARN->ERROR->FATAL -->

</Configuration>
```

Comment: Which framework are you using to consume/produce soap.

Comment: Using maven-jaxb2-plugin, this is what you asked?

Comment: No that is not what I'm asking for. What you are using to send SOAP messages.. Spring WS, Apache CXF what do you use.

Comment: Spring WS, Its in a Spring Boot application

Comment: Then the `logging.level` should work, unless you are adding your own `log4j2.xml`. Try `logging.level.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing=TRACE` (assuming you are only sending and not having a web service yourself).

Comment: I have added my own log4j2.xml. In that case what need to be done ?

Comment: Configure the log level for `org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing` in there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182928/discussion-between-user630209-and-m-deinum).

Comment: Added in log4j2 file, not working. Question updated, added log4j2.xml file

Comment: Please learn your logging framework. It logs to nowhere. There is no appender named `file` or `console`.

Comment: Other loggings  are working,  initializing this using custom  log classes.

Comment: Those aren't configured in your logging configuration. You are sending the logging to non existing appenders so basically it now logs to `/dev/null` aka the trash. Also it appears you are using Log4j syntax in a Log4j2 configuration.

Comment: Also you are not logging debug/trace messages according to your setup as those are being denied.

Comment: I won't add it as an answer unless it's the only thing that ends up working for you, and while it's not based on the spring logging... you can add the following to either your code or the JVM startup param's being used by your application server: `-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`
`-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true`
`-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true`
`-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true`